# Curl of a function with only angular dependence

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis, spherical-coordinates

Let a function in spherical coordinates

$$\vec F(\vec r) = \int{ d^3\vec r\,' \vec j(\vec r\,') } \,e^{-ik\hat r \cdot \vec r \,'}$$
Where $\vec j$ is a vector function.
So $\vec F$ only depends on the angular variables, ie $\vec F(\vec r) = \vec F(\theta, \phi)$. 
Someone says its curl is zero, that is $\nabla \times \vec F = 0$.

How is it derived? Does this result depend on how $\vec F(\theta, \phi)$ is defined (an exponential dependency in the above one), or is it generally true for all functions with only angular dependencies (that is, with no radial dependency)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A  vector field independent of $r$ can have nonzero curl. For example, 
$$\vec F(x,y,z) = \left(\frac{-y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}, \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}},0\right)$$
has nonzero curl: its $z$-component is $1/\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$.

So, the integral form matters.

Actually, I don't think the result is true as stated: my computations do not produce zero curl for this integral, unless something is assumed about $\vec j$.

Here is a similar integral which does have zero curl: 
$$\vec F(\vec r) = \int d^3 \vec v\, \varphi(\vec v) \,g(\vec r\cdot \vec v) \vec v $$
where $\varphi$ and $g$ are arbitrary smooth *scalar-valued* functions.

Indeed, let $G$ be an antiderivative of $g$, that is $G'=g$ (recall these are functions of a scalar argument). Then the chain rule implies
$$\vec F(\vec r) =  \nabla \left ( \int d^3 \vec v\, \varphi(\vec v) \,G(\vec r\cdot \vec v)  \right ) $$
which means $\vec F$ is conservative. Hence it has zero curl.

Comment: If you replace $\phi$ in your last expression with $\vec j/\vec r$, and $G$ with the exponential term, it's almost same with my initial one. I think the point is that the exponential fits the shape of your function $G$. Your last words on expecting $\vec F$ to be conservative enlightened me. Lots of thanks for digging out my immature question!

Comment: @Yvon The last formula in my post is formally similar, but it's a scalar valued integral (with gradient in front). For a vector-valued integral with zero curl, the closest I have is the second-to-last formula. Its important difference from yours is that instead of general vector-valued $\vec j(\vec v)$ I have $\varphi(\vec v) \vec v$; this is a special kind of vector-valued function.

Comment: I checked the context again, and, sadly, we don't have any conditions on $\vec j(\vec v)$. It's an arbitrary space current (density) source, and we want to calc something about the vector potential field. The teacher has deviated from a classic textbook a little, which I don't have access for now. But the result should be true. Anyway, I will re-do it taking conservative field into consideration. That really helps.